# Let users upload videos from my site server to their youtube channel

Tags: php, youtube-api, token, access-token, youtube-data-api

I am running a WordPress site with **ffmpeg** where I allow users to create videos using a form. The videos work fine and are saved in their own directories per post.

I am now trying to allow users to upload the videos they created, to their own youtube channel.

Using PHP code from [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/), and my app from google console, I am able to successfully upload a video to my own account. And it only asks for me to authenticate once.

PHP Code --

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gap/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';

$key = file_get_contents('the_key.txt');

set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gap/google-api-php-client/');
require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$application_name = 'youtube4true'; 
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REMOVED FOR STACK';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REMOVED FOR STACK';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);

    $refresh_token = $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]['refresh_token'];
    file_put_contents('the_key.txt', $refresh_token);
} elseif(file_exists('the_key.txt')) {
    $refresh_token = file_get_contents('the_key.txt');
    $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $access_token = $_SESSION['token']['access_token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);

    $refresh_token = $_SESSION['token']['refresh_token'];
    file_put_contents('the_key.txt', $refresh_token);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $htmlBody = '';
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath =  "HERE I WILL USE AJAX TO PASS THE PATH TO THE VIDEO FILE";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);



// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    try {
        // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
        // currently authenticated user's channel.
        $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
            'mine' => 'true',
        ));

        $htmlBody = '';
        foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
            // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
            // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
            // to retrieve that list.
            $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

            $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
                'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
                'maxResults' => 50
            ));

            $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
            foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
                $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
                    $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
            }
            $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
        }
    } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
            htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $state = mt_rand();
    $client->setState($state);
    $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorise access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Uploaded</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also successfully been able to follow to javascript example to upload from my computer, but the files are stored on the server so that's not what I want.

With javascript, getting a new token for users seems to work, except the file upload issue and that users have to go into their Google accounts to revoke access/log out from my site app.

JS Code -

```
/*
Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
*/

var signinCallback = function (result){
  if(result.access_token) {
    var uploadVideo = new UploadVideo();
    uploadVideo.ready(result.access_token);
  }
};

var STATUS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MILLIS = 60 * 1000; // One minute.


/**
 * YouTube video uploader class
 *
 * @constructor
 */
var UploadVideo = function() {
  /**
   * The array of tags for the new YouTube video.
   *
   * @attribute tags
   * @type Array.<string>
   * @default ['google-cors-upload']
   */
  this.tags = ['test'];

  /**
   * The numeric YouTube
   * [category id](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videoCategories.list?part=snippet&regionCode=us).
   *
   * @attribute categoryId
   * @type number
   * @default 22
   */
  this.categoryId = 22;

  /**
   * The id of the new video.
   *
   * @attribute videoId
   * @type string
   * @default ''
   */
  this.videoId = '';

  this.uploadStartTime = 0;
};


UploadVideo.prototype.ready = function(accessToken) {
  this.accessToken = accessToken;
  this.gapi = gapi;
  this.authenticated = true;
  this.gapi.client.request({
    path: '/youtube/v3/channels',
    params: {
      part: 'snippet',
      mine: true
    },
    callback: function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
        console.log(response.error.message);
      } else {
        $('#channel-name').text(response.items[0].snippet.title);
        $('#channel-thumbnail').attr('src', response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url);

        $('.pre-sign-in').hide();
        $('.post-sign-in').show();
      }
    }.bind(this)
  });
  $('#button').on("click", this.handleUploadClicked.bind(this));
};

/**
 * Uploads a video file to YouTube.
 *
 * @method uploadFile
 * @param {object} file File object corresponding to the video to upload.
 */
UploadVideo.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {
  var metadata = {
    snippet: {
      title: $('#title').val(),
      description: $('#description').text(),
      tags: this.tags,
      categoryId: this.categoryId
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: $('#privacy-status option:selected').text()
    }
  };
  var uploader = new MediaUploader({
    baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos',
    file: file,
    token: this.accessToken,
    metadata: metadata,
    params: {
      part: Object.keys(metadata).join(',')
    },
    onError: function(data) {
      var message = data;
      // Assuming the error is raised by the YouTube API, data will be
      // a JSON string with error.message set. That may not be the
      // only time onError will be raised, though.
      try {
        var errorResponse = JSON.parse(data);
        message = errorResponse.error.message;
      } finally {
        alert(message);
      }
    }.bind(this),
    onProgress: function(data) {
      var currentTime = Date.now();
      var bytesUploaded = data.loaded;
      var totalBytes = data.total;
      // The times are in millis, so we need to divide by 1000 to get seconds.
      var bytesPerSecond = bytesUploaded / ((currentTime - this.uploadStartTime) / 1000);
      var estimatedSecondsRemaining = (totalBytes - bytesUploaded) / bytesPerSecond;
      var percentageComplete = (bytesUploaded * 100) / totalBytes;

      $('#upload-progress').attr({
        value: bytesUploaded,
        max: totalBytes
      });

      $('#percent-transferred').text(percentageComplete);
      $('#bytes-transferred').text(bytesUploaded);
      $('#total-bytes').text(totalBytes);

      $('.during-upload').show();
    }.bind(this),
    onComplete: function(data) {
      var uploadResponse = JSON.parse(data);
      this.videoId = uploadResponse.id;
      $('#video-id').text(this.videoId);
      $('.post-upload').show();
      this.pollForVideoStatus();
    }.bind(this)
  });
  // This won't correspond to the *exact* start of the upload, but it should be close enough.
  this.uploadStartTime = Date.now();
  uploader.upload();
};

UploadVideo.prototype.handleUploadClicked = function() {
  $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
  this.uploadFile($('#file').get(0).files[0]);
};

UploadVideo.prototype.pollForVideoStatus = function() {
  this.gapi.client.request({
    path: '/youtube/v3/videos',
    params: {
      part: 'status,player',
      id: this.videoId
    },
    callback: function(response) {
      if (response.error) {
        // The status polling failed.
        console.log(response.error.message);
        setTimeout(this.pollForVideoStatus.bind(this), STATUS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
      } else {
        var uploadStatus = response.items[0].status.uploadStatus;
        switch (uploadStatus) {
          // This is a non-final status, so we need to poll again.
          case 'uploaded':
            $('#post-upload-status').append('<li>Upload status: ' + uploadStatus + '</li>');
            setTimeout(this.pollForVideoStatus.bind(this), STATUS_POLLING_INTERVAL_MILLIS);
            break;
          // The video was successfully transcoded and is available.
          case 'processed':
            $('#player').append(response.items[0].player.embedHtml);
            $('#post-upload-status').append('<li>Final status.</li>');
            break;
          // All other statuses indicate a permanent transcoding failure.
          default:
            $('#post-upload-status').append('<li>Transcoding failed.</li>');
            break;
        }
      }
    }.bind(this)
  });
};
```

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the refresh or access token. So how can I create an access token for each user instead of only allowing my account on the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working the way I wanted by using the following form on my page -

```
<form id="publish-youtube" action="/path/to/upload.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" id="a_id" name="a_id" value="<?php echo $post_author_id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="vid_id" name="vid_id" value="<?php echo $v_Id; ?>" />
<input type="submit" id="ytu_submit" name="ytu_submit" value="Publish to YouTube">
</form>
```

Then I followed the [youtube api docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) to create my app and my upload.php script, which asks the user to sign in if not already and it uploads the video based on the values from the form ( Note: Im using wordpress ) --

```
<?php
//require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gap/google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php';

set_include_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/gap/google-api-php-client/');
require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Service/YouTube.php';

session_start();

$application_name = 'XXXX'; 
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'XXXX';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXXX';

$videoTitle = $_POST['titlez'];
$authorID = $_POST['a_id'];
$vidID = $_POST['vid_id'];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}
if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

get_header();
global $current_user, $imic_options; // Use global
get_currentuserinfo(); // Make sure global is set, if not set it.

if ((user_can($current_user, "administrator"))||(user_can($current_user, "edit_others_posts")) ):


// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $htmlBody = '';
  try{
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/uploads/".$authorID."/".$vidID."/output-".$vidID.".mp4";

    // Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
    // Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
    // This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
    // video category.
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));
    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);
    $htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title']);
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s" target="_blank">Video Link</a></li>',
        $status['id']);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
        htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == '(I never changed this)REPLACE_ME') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<div id="ytu-container">
<?=$htmlBody?>
</div>

<?php
else: echo imic_unidentified_agent();
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform [the OAUTH dance](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-dance-the-oauth-a-step-by-step-lesson-fd2364d89742)

[image: The Oauth Dance (from FreeCodeCamp)]

Google has some [good documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#obtainingaccesstokens) on the process. The following quoted content and code is pulled from that site.

> 1. Your application identifies the permissions it needs.
> 2. Your application redirects the user to Google along with the list of requested permissions.
> 3. The user decides whether to grant the permissions to your application.
> 4. Your application finds out what the user decided.
> 5. If the user granted the requested permissions, your application retrieves tokens needed to make API requests on the user's behalf.

Code for steps 1 and 2:

```
// setup client (step.1)
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
$client->addScope(GOOGLE_SERVICE_YOUTUBE::YOUTUBE_UPLOAD);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth

// get url and redirect (step.2)
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
exit();
```

You'll need to setup your redirect url to accept the return call from them in the format something like:

`[your_callback_url]/oauth2callback?state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&code=[code]&scope=[scope]`

Then you extract the details from the callback and swap them for a token which will allow you to upload.

```
// swap the code for a token (step.5)
// … do client setup first
// then auth with the code
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
// retrieve the token
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

You can then use that token in your api calls to make calls on behalf of the user.

There is also a [complete example on that same page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#example).